# Trust Relationship between the Primary Domain and the Trusted Domain exception on SecurityIdentifier.Translate

Tags: c#, active-directory

In a script task within SSIS, I am running this block of code

```
SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(memberDN.Substring(0, memberDN.IndexOf(",")).Replace("CN=", ""));
try
{
    NTAccount acct = sid. (NTAccount)sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
    LogonName = acct.Value;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Example script task", ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace + "\n Failed MemberDN:" + memberDN, String.Empty, 0);
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
}
```

This works fine on my local PC in dev environment, but when deployed to the server and run I get this error:

The trust relationship between the primary domain and trusted domain failed at SecurityIdentifier.TranslateToNTAccounts

Failed MemberDN: CN=S-1-5-21-2347892348791324etc.. CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=mlol,DC=local

I'm not really sure how to proceed from here, and how to trace this error further.

Comment: I should add, this exact code was working fine, I then upgraded my SSIS package from 2008 to 2012, re-deployed, and started getting this error. It still works in DEV in VS2012.